# Django + nginx + gunicorn No static files loaded/served

Tags: css, django, nginx, static, gunicorn

I am taking the last steps to making my page public, but after setting up nginx + gunicorn I get the page to load, but none of the css is loading, even though my nginx-log file shows no errors.

Here is my `nginx.conf`:

```
server {
    listen 8000;
    server_name 127.0.0.1;

    access_log /<direct_path>/logs/nginx-access.log;     # <- make sure to create the logs directory
    error_log /<direct_path>/logs/nginx-error.log;       # <- you will need this file for debugging

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9000;         # <- let nginx pass traffic to the gunicorn server
    }

    location /static {
        alias /<project path>/chemicalizer;  # <- let nginx serves the static contents
    }
}
```

and my gunicorn.conf.py, located in same directory as `manage.py`:

```
bind = "127.0.0.1:9000"                   
errorlog = '/<direct_path>/logs/gunicorn-error.log' 
accesslog = '/<direct_path>/logs/gunicorn-access.log'
loglevel = 'debug'
workers = 4
```

and my projects `settings.py` file

```
import os, djcelery
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

# Celery setup
djcelery.setup_loader()
BROKER_URL = 'amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672'

SECRET_KEY = censored...

DEBUG = False
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['0.0.0.0', '127.0.0.1', 'localhost']

# Application definition
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'interface',
    'chemrun',
    'djcelery',
    'kombu.transport.django',
    'chemicalizer.tasks',
    'json',
    'django_nvd3',
    'djangobower',
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'djangosecure',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'djangosecure.middleware.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
)   

ROOT_URLCONF = 'chemicalizer.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': ['interface'],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.i18n',
            'django.template.context_processors.media',
            'django.template.context_processors.static',
            'django.template.context_processors.tz',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
    },
    },
]
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Not sure what other files might be necessary to show so let me know if I should include some other files.

**Update**
After some more looking around I find that my `css` file is loaded and supplied by `nginx`, but somehow the html, or `gunicorn`, is not doing its job. If I look at the contents of the html page using `Chrome's "developer tools"` I find that the css file is located and loaded successfully in the network `part`, but in the `sources` tab the `css` file is empty.

IWhat I also see is that my `gunicorn-access.log` is not sending a `GET` command for the `css` file, is there a reason for that to not happen when the code works without problems when I instead run a `Debug server`?

Comment: What's the system path to your static files?

Comment: /Users/tobias/Dropbox/Science/PythonWorkspace/NewChemicalizer/chemicalizer/static

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution after much trying and found a solution. It appears that I had a small mistake in my `html` that sometimes generated a `GET`. 
But the error causing the css file not to be loaded was that it hard the wrong `mime type`. This was fixed by creating a file `mime.types` in my `/etc/nginx/` directory with the contents

```
types {
    text/css            css;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you're pointing Nginx to your main project directory rather than the directory holding your static files.

```
location /static {
    alias /<project path>/chemicalizer;  # <- let nginx serves the static contents
}
```

should be

```
location /static {
    alias /<project path>/chemicalizer/static;  # <- let nginx serves the static contents
}
```

Comment: Oh I am very glad the solution was that easy. The reason I excluded /static from the path was that I was following [this tutorial](http://cheng.logdown.com/posts/2015/01/29/deploy-django-nginx-gunicorn-on-mac-osx-part-2), and there it said it should be excluded because nginx adds this this. But reading it now I might just have misread it. Many thanks for the quick help!

Comment: This is because you're using "static" instead of "root" as they are in the tutorial - "You might ask why doesn't it forward to '/Users/webapp/Apps/testproject/vis'?(without '/static' in the end) Because when using 'root' in the config, it will append the '/static' part after it. So be aware! You can fix this by using alias instead of root and append /static to the end of the path:"

Comment: It appears I was too quick to jump for joy. Apparently the css file was somehow still in the cache because this morning when I started the server again, the css was not serviced anymore. I tried both options of `alias` with appending `/static` to the end, and `root` without the added `/static`. 
Are there other possible causes to the static files not being found?

Comment: Are you sure you havn't changed anything else? It shouldn't have been in your cache in the first place if it wasn't working at one stage. If you add "autoindex on;" below your alias line, and then browse to http://yoursite.com/static/ - what do you see?

Comment: That was a very nifty command. I added it and going to site.com/static gives me the list of all static files. 
I have tried running the runserver as a debug, where django can supply the static files. I did tried that yesterday briefly in between tries, and imagined that is how it somehow got stuck in a buffer or something. 
Since it works if I run `runserver` instead of through `gunicorn`, the way I load static files can't be the problem, right?
`{% load staticfiles %}` at top of base.html
`<link href="{% static 'css/main.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">` in html head

Comment: Can you browse to your missing CSS file that way? How does the path you browse to it by differ from the one in your generated HTML? (The result of calling {% static 'css/main.css' %})

Comment: The file is there, I find it under `server.com/static/css/main.css`

Comment: What does {% static 'css/main.css' %} output?

Comment: `/static/css/main.css`

Comment: Then it looks like Django & Nginx are both working fine as Django is outputting the path that Nginx is then serving correctly.

Comment: I have looked further into my Chrome and using `developer tools` I can see that the css file is loaded and in the buffer when I load the page. So it is there, but the webserver is just not using it. Is there any obvious reason why it shouldn't, when it all works great if I run a debug server instead?

Comment: I have added an update that includes my findings. Basically the html has an empty css file, but has access to the real css file. Looking through the `gunicorn-access.log` I see no `GET` calls for the css file, only for the page itself that I am loading. Any idea what might be the cause?